# How can I pass an argument to the dependency injection container?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have a class called `GeneralReport`, implementing `HttpAccessibleDataGathererInterface`, with a constructor and a method called `calculate()` that builds an array of plain PHP objects, containing the fields for a report. `GeneralReport` accepts two constructor arguments: one is an array of parameters, which contains the input used to construct the query. The second argument is another class, `GeneralReportQueryBuilder`, to build the query for the report based on the first argument.

Now, I would like the second argument to always be injected (I.E. the `GeneralReportQueryBuilder`). However, I want to somehow be able to pass in the first argument to the `GeneralReport` class in my controller. Keep in mind that the `GeneralReport` class implements an interface, so passing the array as an argument to the `calculate()` method is not an option. Also, since calling this class without an array of input would be pointless, it is not an optional dependency and creating a setter for it wouldn't make sense.

I would like to make the dependencies of `GeneralReport` clear and concise using its constructor, and don't want the DIC to get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between :

- creating a instance without X parameter
- using an instance without X parameter

The first assertion is resolved by constructors parameters, the second by throwing an exception if during execution the parameter is not filled or valid! 
Contextual parameters can be sent by setters !

Comment: Sorry, can you please make your answer less abstract? Do you mean I should have a constructor that only accepts the `GeneralRequestQueryBuilder` and set the array of query parameters using a setter? If so, the problem with this approach is that it hides the fact that you should have the parameters set before calling the `calculate()` method, whereas having the programmer specify the parameters as a required argument of the constructor makes this quite clear.